# Apply solution rules to new functions as parameters

Tags: plotting, functions, replacement

**Update: I put an screenshot of how my code and problem look like at the end.**

Say that *Mathematica* solved a system of equations and got two answers {{a -> 3, b -> c, d -> 0}, {a -> -3, b -> 0, c -> 1/2d}}. (These answers are completely made up and don't mean anything) I want to plug in those numbers/rules in the function f = a*x + b*y + c*z + d and do contourPlot3D with f==0.

The thing is if I apply rules and get the substituted expression and manually paste the expression in contourPlot3D, it works fine, but if I try to do it in a more systematic way, it doesn't work.

So this doesn't work:

```
solution = Solve[constraints, {g[1], g[2], g[3], g[4], h[1], h[2], h[3], h[4]}];
gplot[k_] := g[1]*x + g[2]*y + g[3]*z + g[4] /. solution[[k]];
hplot[k_] := h[1]*x + h[2]*y + h[3]*z + h[4] /. solution[[k]];
Manipulate[
ContourPlot3D[gplot[1] == 0, , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}], 
  {g[1], -1, 1}, {g[4], -2, 2}, {h[2], -1, 1}, {h[4], -2, 2}]
```

But this works, :

```
Manipulate[
ContourPlot3D[x g[1] + y g[1] + g[4] == 0, , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}], 
  {g[1], -1, 1}, {g[4], -2, 2}, {h[2], -1, 1}, {h[4], -2, 2}]
```

I thought gplot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bd7b.jpg) should be the same as x g[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bd7b.jpg) + y g[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bd7b.jpg) + g[4], as that's how I copy paste into the  contourplot function, but then as I print out gplot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bd7b.jpg) again, it changes to -2.22222*10^-7 g[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bd7b.jpg) + g[4]. I think this is what's causing the plot to fail, but I don't understand why this happens. Why did my x,y,z variables turn into weird constants?

Or is there another way to apply solution rules to new functions as parameters and plot the equations that can avoid such problems?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: In your example gplot[1] has its parameters g[1] .. g[4] replaced with the solution, so there are no variables for the Manipulate left to play with.

Comment: But x,y,z should remain variables.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that g[1] etc are not part anymore of the plot equation. So, you end up with a fixed plot (after you have removed the erroneous comma in your plot command) that doesn't change anymore when the g's and h's are manipulated.

Comment: I think that @SjoerdC has pinpointed the mechanical cause of the failure of your Manipulate, but I think that there is also some conceptual problem here. It would be helpful if you could show us what `solutions` looks like in your case. For instance, I am not sure what is causing that value of the `gplot[1]` function. Is there any chance that you might have some lingering definitions for your variables leftover from previous execution? Have you tried in a fresh kernel (from the menus, "Evaluation -> Quit kernel -> Local")?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Oh I see what you mean. The thing is the solution does not give numerical value to every parameter, that's why I used Manipulate for g[1] and g[4]. solution[[1]] is actually this: {g[2] -> g[1], g[3] -> 0, h[1] -> 0, h[3] -> 0}. And I think Manipulate worked, because I see a interface to change g[1] and g[4], but the ContourPlot didn't recognize my equation and where there's suppose to be the graph, there is the code for ContourPlot.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for the advice, I tried starting with a new kernel but it doesn't help.

Comment: I have marked your question as a duplicate because I believe from your update that it is one.  Please read that question and attempt to apply the methods therein.  If that does not solve your problem please edit this question to reference that question and explain how your situation is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running afoul of the (beneficial) scoping that is applied inside `Manipulate` constructs by way of [`DynamicModule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule.html) (or the low-level equivalent).  If you "inject" the expression containing `g[1]` etc. into the `Manipulate` before it is evaluated it should work correctly I believe:

```
With[{body = gplot[1] == 0},
  Manipulate[
   ContourPlot3D[body, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}],
   {g[1], -1, 1}, {g[4], -2, 2}, {h[2], -1, 1}, {h[4], -2, 2}
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now!   I don't quite understand what you mean by "way of Dynamic Module" though.  And how does using With[{body = gplot[1] == 0} inject the expression before it's evaluated?  I'm very new to Mathematica, so I should apologize first for my tons of questions.

Comment: @Xilin You're diving into the deep end when working with Dynamic expressions as thought they appear simple they are actually rather involved.  (`Manipulate` is an abstraction for dynamic functionality.)  `DynamicModule` is a special variation of `Module`.  It is the scoping construct that should be used with dynamic expressions.  In *Mathematica* this localization is "emulated" by renaming Symbols on-the-fly.  Your Symbols must appear inside `Manipulate` before it is evaluated for the localization (renaming) to work properly. (continued)

Comment: `With` replaces literal appearances of a given Symbol with a given expression in the body (second argument) of the `With` expression *before* that expression is further evaluated.  Consider for example `x = 2;
With[{x = 5}, Print[x]];` -- `5` is printed because `x` in `Print[x]` is replaced with `5` before `Print` is evaluated.  Note that `x` still has the value of `2` after running this code.

Comment: @Xilin By the way I like [this example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/633/121) best for understanding the basic *Mathematica* scoping constructs.

Comment: Thank you, your examples are vey helpful!!!